# How to control when does the console shows in python

Tags: python, console

I am making a python script that shows content in the console for the first 10-20 seconds after executed before the tkinter UI is shown. So is there any lines I can add to control the visibility of the console? .pyw file extension completely disables the console but I need the console to occasionally show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to write your entire Tkinter code under a function.

```
def main_program():
        # root = Tk() ...
```

Below this you need to write an empty print statement for the console. Below this, you can write anything. But the problem is sometimes, console quickly opens, prints the statement and closes it, so you barely have time to see
So, use `time.sleep()` -

```
import time
from tkinter import *
def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.mainloop()

print('Wait for a second')
time.sleep(1)
main()
```

This will show the print statement, delay the program for 1 second, and then open Tkinter window.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it.

You can withdraw the window, print whatever you want and at the last, make it visible. `.withdraw` basically hides the window without any changes to the widgets.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.withdraw()
print("Hey there! Please wait for 10 seconds for the app to start...")
root.after(10000,lambda: root.deiconify())
root.mainloop()
```

Or, the second one is

```
from tkinter import *
import time
def create_window():
        root = Tk()
        root.mainloop()
print('Hey there! Please wait for 10 seconds for the app to start...')
time.sleep(10)
create_window()
```